# insert all from table1 to table2 having different table structure

Tags: mysql

`table1` have columns `id` `what` `title` **and** five columns more;

`table2` have **only** columns `id` `what` and `title`;

How to insert all rows from from `table2` into `table1`?

`insert into table1 select * from table2` - doesn't work because of different table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below -

```
insert into table1(id, what, title) 
    select id, what, title from table2
```

Comment: are you sure about `id` column? it is auto increment

Comment: though you've not provided your table structure, but it seems to me okay if your id column does not include identity insert on @puerto

Comment: anyway, I just removed `id` from your code and - it works. thanks a lot. solved